# Can I add an Azure data factory service principal inside Azure Databricks to grant it access to run notebooks rather than giving it "Contributor" role

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I followed [this link](https://www.kimanimbugua.com/post/set-up-azure-databricks-managed-identity-in-data-factory) to use MSI authentication for Axure Data factory to configure and run my Azure Databricks notebooks.

This requires ADF managed identity to have "Contributor" permissions.

Question1:
Is it possible to use "Reader" permissions to create the linked services and run the notebooks ?

Question2:
In case we decide to assign permissions to ADF MSI inside the "Users and Groups" section in Admin console in the Databricks - can we do so ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you please provide the error if any got?

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: @bhavani - I tried assigning "Reader" role to MSI of ADF -it gave 403 unauthorized error and was not able to kick off the notebook .  Then I tried with "Contributor" role and it somehow created and adds some Service principal ( not the actual MSI object ID) in "admins" group in the Databricks workspace. Now this Service Principal/ID is saved there.   Now I changed the role to "Reader" again and it still ececutes the notebook successfully. Wonder how that Service Principal gets created and how the permission remains intact even after changing the role.

Comment: @Bhavani - Post this, I deleted the role from IAM and it still runs fine with no roles.    Now, I delete the Service Principal from "admins" group  in Databricks and now it starts failing again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have contributor permissions, reader does not grant you any kind of edits or creates, including linked services etc. Reader is a very restricted BuiltInRole type as defined by IAM "View all resources but does not allow you to make any changes."

Question2: You still need to configure everything according to documentation with MSI, there is no other way to do it.

Comment: Hi @ziya-mert-karakas  -- so we mean to say IAM role to ADF is a must to run the notebook even If we are somehow able to access the MSI for ADF inside Databricks synced via Unity catalog and permissions assigned there ?

Comment: Have you actually tried that? This should not work but i am curious about what message are you getting when you do that. In a way you are trying to override the linked service settings here. ADF will still not allow you to do that and you should be getting some kind of error

Comment: I don't have Databricks Account  Admin access and AD access so could not enable Unity metastore. Also - I create my Linked service using MSI but did not "Test connection" and simply created it.  Until I execute it - the Service Principal doesn't get created in "admin" group in Databricks.. Please refer to my comments in above answer